Why do we need 50 points to comment?
Just wanted to say the policy of requiring 50 reputation for posting comments has the unfortunate effect of newcomers being unable to respond to comments directed at them in the appropriate place. Some will give up, others will gain the 50 points and then reply, while others will "hack" it by responding in answers (requires 0 rep). Some will also, in the same spirit, make a further mess of this board by complaining about it on the main site instead of in meta. The mechanisms intended to keep the boards neat might work against their purpose when the rules don't make sense. If I can ask and answer, I don't see how banning me from commenting makes sense.
The particular instance this question is related to:
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8667/asymetric-bodily-development-correlating-to-asym-brain-development

This is pointless. You could have just edited your question responding to Chris Stronks as Seanny123 suggested.

This is a meta question and signing up is too easy. Also, as @LarryM. indicates, you could have simply edited the question slightly. Everyone started off in SE from scratch and the reputation rules are in place for a reason. Misplaced questions won't do your reputation any good either. But again, this discussion should be held elsewhere.

I know this post is off topic and should be deleted, but the OP is right. I've seen people responding using answers. And those responses actually were sometimes too useful for anyone to flag them.

@udhd Try to make your point on meta.

@TomášZato if you flag cases where answers are used to address comments, a mod can convert the answer into a comment.

On Stack Overflow, comments are allowed as replies to comments regardless of reputation (at least, I have seen people with 1 rep commenting before). Not sure why it would be different here.

This seems like an unnecessary restriction. Who benefits here, exactly? We should lower the barrier to something more reasonable, like 5 or 10 reputation. Having mods convert answers into comments is beyond a waste of mods' time.

i'm downvoting because it serves a purpose of keeping people from disturbing others

lots of random thanks! good job! and other stuff happen otherwise

Seems like a phantom problem. I haven't seen a single comment like that to begin with, and I strongly doubt it's this rule keeping the +1 riff-raff out.

why do you get to call people rift raff?

Because that's the view your desire to keep people with <50 rep from commenting, lest they sin against the comment system, conveyed to me. (It is a snub.) Frankly, I wouldn't even mind if people posted +1 or thanks at our current activity levels. Anything to engage people more with the site is fine by me.

naw don't do that man...your off in other threads saying the less experienced or esl people require your  "edits" and complaining and stuff ...i'm merely saying that the short messages they leave do not contribute to the question or answer and are chat rather than comments

giving them comment privileges would only hurt their feelings at the strange atypical responses people here give

There's no more reason to believe that >50 reputation users are more able to handle comment responses than there is to believe that lowering the  commenting privileges threshold to five would result in a deluge of +1 and thanks comments. There's actually every reason to believe this is not the case, since other, larger SE sites like SO manage just fine.

consistent observation...most people are wt? when they get here and they are slammed for not reading the book on how to deal with people here
